# How can we rescue this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What do the Valar actually do in the Third Age?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83643/what-does-manw%C3%AB-do-all-day-and-all-the-night)

This question was asked, and in it's original incarnation closed as "unclear what you're asking".

I subsequently edited it, in order to remove some elements that would make it closable (but for a different close reason), added a comment requesting that the asker tighten up the focus a little, and it started to get some reopen votes.

However, it's now been closed again, and again as "unclear what you're asking".

The thing is: **even as it stands, the question is perfectly answerable with references from the source material**.

I'm personally reluctant to go hacking and slashing through the question text any more as I feel it would risk changing the asker's intent too much, but I do think that is a potentially good question and I'd like to see it rescued.  But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my bad. I should have made it clear that I closed it (as unclear) because it's two different questions.

You can rescue it by making it a single answerable question or posting a comment explaining how the two (distinct) questions are related to each other.

Comment: OK, I've edited a bit more in an attempt to focus it without (I hope) being too destructive.

Comment: IMHO, "two different question" - while may be worth closing as too broad - is NOT in any way falling under "unclear"